# haystack search is not returning results properly, error: list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, django-search-lucene

I am a noob in django and haystack,
This is my form that extends haystack SearchForm

```
from haystack.forms import SearchForm
from ksaprice_app.models import ProductDiff, Vendor
from django import forms
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
class ProductsSearchForm(SearchForm):
    vendor_list=Vendor.objects.all().values_list('vendor_name')
    OPTIONS=( (item,str(item)) for item in vendor_list)
    print OPTIONS    select_vendor=forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=OPTIONS, required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductsSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def search(self):
      sqs=super(ProductsSearchForm, self).search()
      if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()
    #check to see if the submitted is clean and then filter
      if self.is_valid():               
        if self.cleaned_data['select_vendor']:
            #name of the field in html will be by default form field name
            vendor_filter=self.cleaned_data['select_vendor']
            #v_filter=vendor_filter[0].replace("(u'","").replace("',)","")
            v_filter=vendor_filter[0]
            print v_filter
            #sqs=SearchQuerySet().filter(product_vendor_name=v_filter)[:10]
            sqs=sqs.filter(product_vendor_name=v_filter)[:10] ##error is here
    return sqs
    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()[:10]
```

and this is view

```
def ProductsSearch(request):
#instantiate the form with parameters from get method
  form = forms.ProductsSearchForm(request.GET)
  #calling search method here that fetches the search result
  context_var={}
  context_var['products'] = form.search()
  context_var['form']=forms.ProductsSearchForm
  print context_var
  return render_to_response('ksaprice_app/product_search.html', {'context_var': context_var})
```

at sqs.filter, I am getting this error `'list' object has no attribute 'filter'`. I followed the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html) and the [example](http://blog.ingenuity.ph/2013/04/haystack-solr-search-and-wkhtmltopdf-in.html). I am not able to figure out, what the problem is?. search method is returning list object instead of SearchQuerySet object, and hence not able to find filter attribute. please help.
I am using python 2.7.10, Django 1.8.4 and solr 4.10.2
sqs is

[image]

Comment: Where do you define sqs? the previous line is commented out

Comment: @xbirkettx sorry that line got deleted while formating code to post question. it is defined as `sqs=super(ProductsSearchForm, self).search()` in search method, please check the code now...

Comment: Your code seems ok, what is inside sqs, if you print it?

Comment: sqs is `[<SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4001')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4002')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4003')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4004')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4005')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4006')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4007')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4008')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4009')>, <SearchResult: ksaprice_app.product (pk=u'4010')>]
` @xbirkettx i have added a picture of sqs in the question, please look at it..

Answer (score 1):

After 3-4 days I reached at solution.

Solution 1-: Change in schema

**Step1:** Go to your collection managed-schema file and edit
**Step2 :** Find and replace `<field name="django_ct" type="text_general"/>` to `<field name="django_ct" type="string"/>`

- Operating system version: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Search engine version: Solr 7.2.1
- Python version: 3.4.3
- Django version: 2.0
- Haystack version: 2.8.0

Solution 2-: Hack core file

**Step1:** sudo vim /home/your path/site-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py
**Step2:** Find and replace `app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT].split('.')` to `app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT][0].split('.')`

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

```
sudo vim /home/your path/site-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py
```

Step2: Find and replace
`app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT].split('.')`
with
`app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT][0].split('.')`
step3 : Find and replace
`result = result_class(app_label, model_name, raw_result[DJANGO_ID], raw_result['score'], **additional_fields)`
with
`result = result_class(app_label, model_name, raw_result[DJANGO_ID][0], raw_result['score'], **additional_fields)`